# Generate Random String with Specific Restrictions

Tags: lua

Tring to generate a random string but it needs to be formatted a specific way.

N = number
L = Capital Letter

must be NL-NN

needs hyphen as well

examples: 5K-22, 9L-19, 0R-66

every method I have tried has just generated a string but without the hyphen, I know it is probably something simple my brain just hurts thinking on it so I thought I'd see if one of yall could give me a hand.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function randomchar(a,b)
    return string.char(math.random(string.byte(a),string.byte(b)))
end

a=randomchar('0','9')
b=randomchar('A','Z')
c=randomchar('0','9')
d=randomchar('0','9')

print(a..b..'-'..c..d)
```

Comment: This assumes letters are consecutive in the encoding, which is not true in EBCDIC :-)